# Content not updating with firebase serve --only hosting

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I'm trying to test changes to [my site](https://pwatest.app).  But when I make changes and restart `firebase serve --only hosting` the changes aren't showing up.

I'm using Vuejs if that matters...

Answer (score 6):

i had this problem but it turns out chrome cached my old version and is putting it every time

just disable the cache from chrome from devtools

https://www.technipages.com/google-chrome-how-to-completely-disable-cache

With Chrome, you can have the cache disable when DevTools are open by selecting the "Disable cache" option in the Network tab.

Answer (score 0):

If I use `npm run dev` I see the content changes immediately with hot reloading.  Not sure how `npm run dev` is different from `firebase serve --hosting only` or why you need `firebase serve` at all when developing hosting.

You need to run `npm run build` before `firebase serve --hosting only` too.  When using `firebase serve`

The issues seems to be that the emulator hosting doesn't do hot reloading.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well. The easiest way of fixing this is to clear cache and cookies, and reload.

Answer (score -1):

I just do this in the console

```
npm run build && firebase deploy
```

(To build into the dist folder AND deploy to firebase hosting)

my firebase.json file looks like this

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

When all this is done, I log into firebase hosting on the browser, and I delete the previous uploads. Though it will take time for Firebase to update its CDN (probably after 10 minutes), with the new code.